# Rotate image got from uri

Tags: android, matrix

i have an imageviewer app component that is receiving images from uri. How can I rotate it ? Matrix doesn't seem to work. This is my code

public class ImageViewer extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStatey);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_view_layout);
    Uri uri = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getData() : null;
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setImageURI(uri);
    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: Check the following link http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

Comment: That example is loading bitmap but I am getting the image from uri

Comment: You can retrieve a Bitmap Object using your Uri and then apply rotations too!

Answer (score 0):

some android rotate code. supply your URI to the decoder...

```
                            Bitmap lbit =   
                            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                                    getContentResolver().openInputStream(_uri),null,options);

                            Log.i(TAG, "Rotating... " + rotation);
                            lbit = lbit.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
                            lbit = Bitmap.createBitmap(lbit, 0, 0, lbit.getWidth(),
                                    lbit.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```